# Notepad++ - Converting a single column into multiple columns

Tags: microsoft-excel, notepad++

I have some data I'm trying to get from a copy and paste from a website into Excel. the problem is that the output is like this:

```
User1
Administrator
111
User2
Guest
321
User3
Guest
443
```

And I'd like it to appear as:

```
User1  Administrator  111
User2  Guest          321
User3  Guest          443
```

Is this possible to do with Notepad++?

Comment: Is there a particular reason to add Notepad++ into the chain rather than fixing it after it's in Excel?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, this is possible with multi-line regular expressions

**Requirements:**

1. Last line MUST be blank (to match newline for last row of text)
2. The second-to-last line number MUST be a multiple of three
3. The cursor MUST be at the beginning of the document (Ln: 1, Col: 1)

**Steps:**

1. Click on Search (menu), Replace
2. Find what: `([^\r]*)\r\n([^\r]*)\r\n([^\r]*)\r\n`
3. Replace with: `\1\t\2\t\3\r\n`
4. Search mode: Regular expression
5. Enable ". matches newline"
6. Click "Replace All"

**Note:** If a mistake messes up the formatting, click the text and click Undo.

**Regular Expression Explanation:**

- The option ". matches newline" treats the entire document as one long line
- The three `([^\r]*)\r\n` match each line

  - `[^\r]*` matches characters that are not a carriage return
  - `( )` saves those characters in a group, later printed with `\1` `\2` and `\3`
  - `\r\n` matches, but does not save the two-character Windows newline
  - `\1\t\2\t\3\r\n` displays each group, separated by a tab (for Excel), followed by a newline.

Comment: I nearly got this, but being so used to Linux I forgot about the `\r`! In fact I was using `(^.*$)` for each line and this works equally well. Although it doesn't do any harm, you don't actually need `. matches newline`, since you don't use `.` in your search string (I didn't need it for my search string, either).